# Youtube Shorts rendered as normal youtube video and not shorts

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to update my site so it handles Youtube shorts and for some reason it is not doing it, however if I go into the console and manually replace with the exact same URL in the source it all of a sudden recognises it as a Youtube Short.

This is my `iframe`:

```html
<iframe class="product__image__main__iframe" data-lazy="false" data-video_type="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mdEQ_Tx8nww?enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

When the page first renders it shows it as a normal youtube video.

If I replace the code above in the console with the exact same code manually then it recognises it as a Short.

See screenshots
[image: This is a short but being shown as a normal youtube video]

[image: Upon replacing the source in the iframe in the console all of a sudden shows up as a short]

[image: And plays it as a Youtube shorts]

I've tried different protocols: `http` vs `https`

Deleting the `enablejsapi=1` part